# Laravel - Routing to update error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I encounter a error:

```
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("users") to generate a URL for route "users.update".
```

I have this set on my view:

```
{{ Form::open( array('action' => array('UsersController@update')) )  }}

         <div>  {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
            {{ Form::text('username', $user->username , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}</div> 

             <div>  {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address:') }}
            {{ Form::text('email', $user->email , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}</div> 

            <div>  {{ Form::label('new_password', 'New Password:') }}
            {{ Form::text('new_password', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }} </div> 

             <div>  {{ Form::label('old_password', 'Old Password:') }}
            {{ Form::text('password', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }} </div>

            {{ Form::submit() }}


{{ Form::close() }}
```

I also have a function in my controller linked to update:

```
public function update() {
        return 'This is an update';
    }
```

And finally, when I check all the routes available in Artisan command, I found that the update has a route to: `users/{users}`

What's wrong with my codes? I'm trying to update a user and it throws this error.

Comment: you are missing the `{user}` parameter in the action attribute of your form. __in simple terms__, you are missing the 2nd parameter in `{{ Form::open( array('action' => array('UsersController@update')) )  }}`. it should be like `{{ Form::open( array('action' => array('UsersController@update', $id)) )  }}` where id is the id of the user.

Comment: Yes. I just found that out recently but still that doesn't solve the problem because it is for update. There's no need to set those variables for actions like update, store and delete.

Comment: change the route to `users` then in routes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is defined in a way to expect a variable $users to be passed. because of the: `{users}`

Instead, you should define it like:

```
Route::post('users/update', 'UsersController@update');
```

and then in your function update() get the post variable by:

```
$users_data = Input::get();
```

OR

if you want to keep the parameter, redefine the form by passing additional parameter:

```
{{ Form::open( array('action' => array('UsersController@update', $id)) ) }}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem but it was an update so I use: Route::put() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are opening the FORM, it is needs a route paramenter. If you dont want to pass parameters, just use the following:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'UsersController@update')) }}
```

Instead of:

```
{{ Form::open( array('action' => array('UsersController@update')) )  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you're setting a action, you may still need a route for it. I STRONGLY recommend you to always use CLEARED DEFINED routes to your controllers. See if the [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) helps you, in case you don't wanna to define every god damm route (I DON'T).

And, finally answering your question: I think a

```
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'UsersController@update')) }}
```

...may solve your problem. Hope it helps. Sorry for my bad english! :D